# Why do we have to cast Immutable to Pair in some cases?

Tags: java

The following code gives me compilation error:

```
//C1 c1 = ....;
//C2 c2 = ....;
List<Pair<Pair<C1, String>, C2>>> l = someMethod().stream()
         .map(item -> ImmutablePair.of(ImmutablePair.of(c1, "hello"), c2))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But when I change it to the following, it works fine:

```
//C1 c1 = ....;
//C2 c2 = ....;
List<Pair<Pair<C1, String>, C2>>> l = someMethod().stream()
         .map(item -> {
               Pair<Pair<C1, String>, C2> r = ImmutablePair.of(ImmutablePair.of(c1, "hello"), c2);
               return r;
         })
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I thought maybe it's because of casting (which I don't get why it should need to be casted) and I change the code to the following, but I still see the "Incompatible type" error:

```
//C1 c1 = ....;
//C2 c2 = ....;
List<Pair<Pair<C1, String>, C2>>> l = someMethod().stream()
         .map(item -> 
               (Pair<Pair<C1, String>, C2>)ImmutablePair.of(ImmutablePair.of(c1, "hello"), c2)
         })
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How can I write this in one line to work? and why doesn't it figure out itself? What's the ambiguity?

Comment: What is return type of `someMethod()`, what is `c1` and `c2`, and why aren't you using `item`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po)

Comment: This has to do with Java's generic system. `List<Object>` is not a supertype of `List<String>`. The same goes for your case: `List<Pair<...>>` is not a supertype of `List<ImmutablePair<...>>`

Comment: then why second case succeeds, and not the third one?

Comment: In the second case, the same thing is happening: `Pair<Pair<...>>` is not a super type of `ImmutablePair<ImmutablePair<...>>`. Try casting it to `Pair<? extends Pair<C1, String>, C2>`

Comment: but the second case doesn't give compilation error.

Comment: Good point. I am not sure then why that works and the other one doesn't

Comment: Just as a sidenote, if you return `return ImmutablePair.of((Pair<C1, String>)ImmutablePair.of(c1, "hi"), c2);`, it works. I'm still convinced this problem has to do with the lack of contravariant inheritance in Java, but I don't have full knowledge of every aspect of it, especially with assignment and inheritance

Answer (score 0):

The compiler can't infer the types of your Pair. This happens when one of your types is generic as well. In this case, explicitly telling the compiler what your types are should work.

```
List<Pair<Pair<C1, String>, C2>>> l = someMethod().stream()
         .map(item -> ImmutablePair.<Pair<C1, String>, C2>>of(ImmutablePair.of(c1, "hello"), c2))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```